# swiftUI tabView pagetabviewstyle - button to next is not working

Tags: button, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

```
import SwiftUI
```

GuideImageView
currentPage mean 1VStack which is in text and images from array from guidelists

```
struct GuideImageView: View {
@State var currentPage: Int = 0
var body: some View {
VStack{
    TabView(selection: $currentPage){
        ForEach(guidelists){i in
            VStack{
                Text(i.explain)
                Image(i.image)
                    .resizable()
            }
        }
    }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))  //page처럼 구현 + ...을 안보이게함
    
    Button("Next") {
if currentPage == 3 {
                currentPage = 0
                //return
            }else{
                currentPage += 1
            }            
    }
}
}
}
```

Struct GuideList

```
struct GuideList: Identifiable, Hashable{//가이드리스트 구조체, 이미지와 설명넣기
let id = UUID() //UUID = 고유식별자
let image: String
let explain: String
}
```

let guidelists

```
let guidelists = [
GuideList(image: "image1",explain: "explain1." ),
GuideList(image: "image2",explain: "explain2." ),
GuideList(image: "image3",explain: "explain3." )
]
```

GuideImageView_Previews

```
struct ImageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
GuideImageView()
}
}
```

I want to make button to go to next page
button seems doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this not working is the **type mismatch** in your models id and the selection var.

---

Detail:

```
TabView(selection: $currentPage){
            ForEach(guidelists){i in
```

these two lines tell the compiler that the id for every element is of type `UUID` (because `GuideList` is identifieable and `id` is of type `UUID`. Thats fine for itself, but TabView has a selection var of type `Int` (`currentPage` is an `Int`) so it is not working. So changing one of both types to equal the other will solve the problem.

---

easy example:

Change your code to:

```
struct GuideList: Identifiable, Hashable{//가이드리스트 구조체, 이미지와 설명넣기
    let id: Int
    let image: String
    let explain: String
}

let guidelists = [
    GuideList(id: 0, image: "image1",explain: "explain1."),
    GuideList(id: 1, image: "image2",explain: "explain2." ),
    GuideList(id: 2, image: "image3",explain: "explain3." )
]
```